# JAXB unmarshals incomplete objects when using XSD <choice> element 

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I'm experiencing a problem unmarshalling a  element in an XML document using JAXB RI 2.2.1.

The element is defined as follows (the full XSD is too large to post):

```
<xsd:element name="PatternExpression" type="PatternExpression_Type"/>

<xsd:complexType name="PatternExpression_Type">
  <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element ref="Pattern"/>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="PatternOperator"/>
      <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Pattern"/>
        <xsd:element ref="PatternExpression" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Here is the XML I'm trying to unmarshal:

```
<PatternExpression>
  <PatternOperator tc="2">and</PatternOperator>
  <Pattern>
    <PropertyName>FirstName</PropertyName>
    <PropertyValue>John</PropertyValue>
  </Pattern>    
  <Pattern>
    <PropertyName>LastName</PropertyName>
    <PropertyValue>Doe</PropertyValue>
  </Pattern>
</PatternExpression>
```

When I run the document through the unmarshaller, the resulting PatternExpression object contains the PatternOperator and a single Pattern, which happens to be the last one in the sequence.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the Pattern objects are not being added to the list?

I would think that the presence of the PatternOperator would allow JAXB to determine what choice the element fall into.

FYI, the XML schema is controlled by a 3rd party, so it cannot be modified.

Comment: What does your corresponding object model (for this fragment) look like?

Comment: The generated Java class should contain a Pattern field, a PatternOperator field, and then a List of Objects which contains Patterns and PatternExpressions.  So, because your XML has a PatternOperator, the Pattern field should be null and the List of Objects should contain two Patterns.  How did you generate the JAX-B Java source code...maybe it is incorrect..

Comment: I'm using XJC with the following global bindings to generate the source code:     <jxb:globalBindings
         fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true"
         typesafeEnumBase="xs:NCName"
         choiceContentProperty="false"
         typesafeEnumMemberName="generateError"
         enableFailFastCheck="true"   
         generateIsSetMethod="true"
         underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>

Comment: @user410879: Your schema does not validate: `com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Element "Pattern" shows up in more than one properties.`. Indeed, `<Pattern>` should be validated as choice->element or choice->sequence->choice->element ?